# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/xx

Tags: php, pdo

I get this error. I am 11 years old and learning. Appreciate your help

This is my code.Thank you in advance.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<?php
$dsn = "xxxxxx_xxxx"
$user = "xxxxxx_xxxxxx"
$password = "xxxxxx"
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, 
           array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem',
                 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem',
                 PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem'));

    echo "Connestion established";
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: Missing `;` in `$dsn =...`, `$user = ...` and `$password = ...`

Comment: Make Google you friend, search for the error message and you would probably have found this duplicate question and others

Answer (score 0):

These three lines are missing semicolons at the end:

```
$dsn = "xxxxxx_xxxx";
$user = "xxxxxx_xxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
```

Comment: I try semicolons but this don't change anything

Comment: @Mert2006, It should have moved you past the error you were getting in the subject of your post, probably to another error. Even though I did answer your question correctly (and you don't know it) I got downvoted for this answer, so I'm done.